# How can I add the values of pandas columns with the same name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like as follows:

[image]

I have several columns with the same names. I would like to combine those columns in one and sum the values in them. For example in the first row, foot comes up 5 times as a column name. I would like to combine those 5 into one foot column with the sum of the values (1).

For the dataframe above I would like this to be combined to become:

```
finger foot forearm glute groin
  0     1    0       0      0
  0     0    0       0      0
  0     0    0       0      0
  0     0    0       0      0
  0     0    0       0      0
```

Essentially the 5 columns that have finger are combined into one column with header finger and the sum of all the items in that row is 0. Similarly, the six columns with foot are combined into one column called foot and the sum is taken of all the 6 columns in that particular row which is 1. I would like to do this for all the columns and have the sum of every item with the same column name. 
How could I do this?

Comment: Try to add an example dataset in the form of text, so we can copy and use it create an answer. We cannot copy pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

**Here is an example**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':[2,3]})
df=pd.concat([df,df],axis=1)
print(df)

   col1  col2  col1  col2
0     1     2     1     2
1     2     3     2     3

new_df=df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum()
print(new_df)

   col1  col2
0     2     4
1     4     6
```

`axis = 1` tells pandas that we want to make groups by columns, and `level = 0` tells it that we want to divide the groups based on level 0 of the columns (because axis=1), in this case there is only one level in the columns because there is no [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) in columns, another way to do this would be:

```
new_df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()

   col1  col2
0     2     4
1     4     6
```

Comment: This actually just outputs a sum of all the columns if there is a 1 in one of the columns. So for the first row it outputs 6 for foot because there are 6 columns with the name foot.

Comment: I have edited my post to give an expected output with a description.

Comment: I think that code should work perfectly, please check it, if not, include a somewhat more representative data frame (with more ones in different positions)

Comment: can anyone please explain what "level = 0" is doing exactly?